# How to send input from HTML form and use it in php CURL then send it to another php file

Tags: php, curl

Im having a problem with this. I have this form

```
<form action="https://ipg.e-biner.com:7000/bayaro/GetToken" name="" method="post">

            <input type="hidden" name="username" value="av" />

            <input type="hidden" name="password" value="a" />

            <input type="hidden" name="total" value="25000" />

            <input type="hidden" name="items" value="a" />

            <input type="hidden" name="trxid" value="12345678" />

            <input type="hidden" name="voucher_code" value="" />

            <input type="hidden" name="successUrl" value=""/>

            <input type="hidden" name="failedUrl" value=""/>

            <input type="submit" value="Checkout" />
        </form>
```

The response might be a JSON format like this {"token":"20170214111050614349","trxid":"123803742384723874","validthru":
"1487345450","rc":"0"}

I need to use the token number from that response to another php file. This is my code, I know this is might be wrong somehow.

```
    if (isset($_POST['Checkout']))
{   ?>
<?php
//JSON URL which should be requested
$json_url = 'https://ipg.e-biner.com:7000/bayaro/GetToken';
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );
$options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
       CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json') ,
       CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $jsonstring
);
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options ); //Setting curl options
$result =  curl_exec($ch); //Getting jSON result string
$jsonstring=file_get_contents($json_url);
$decode = json_decode($result, true);
foreach($decode as $row){
        echo $row;
}
?>;

<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "New.php";
</script> 
<?php } ?>;
```

and this is the another php file that I want to give the token

```
    <?php
$row=(isset ($_GET['token']));
?>

<form action="https://ipg.e-biner.com:7000/bayaro/Pay" method="post">

            <input type="hidden" value='token' name="token" />

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
$decode = json_decode($result, true);
$token = $decode['token'];
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var token = <?php echo $token;?>
window.location = "New.php?token="+token;
</script>
```

And in another php file

```
<?php
$token= $_GET['token'];//get value
?>

<form action="https://ipg.e-biner.com:7000/bayaro/Pay" method="post">

            <input type="hidden" value='<?php echo $token;?>' name="token" />

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: Its still stacked at https://ipg.e-biner.com:7000/bayaro/GetToken when the JSON format appeared. It wouldnt move to another php file sir. Sorry, Im new here :(